# Mailchimp API 3.0 Batch Subscribe

Tags: curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Acconding to the documentation a POST to /lists/{list_id} should batch subscribe or unsubscribe list members.

If I send two members; one new member and one unsubscribed member:

```
    {
        "update_existing":true,
        "members":[
            {
                "email_address":"yyyy@yyy.yy",
                "email_type":"html",
                "status":"subscribed"
            },
            {
                "email_address":"xxx@xxx.xx",
                "email_type":"html",
                "status":"subscribed"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The documentation(http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#create-post_lists_list_id), states that the resulting JSON will include an array with new_members, updated_members and an array with members with errors:

> Response body parameters
>
> Errors: An array of objects, each representing an email address that could not be added to the list or updated and an error message providing more details.

.

But instead I get a HTTP Status 400 with the following error:

```
{
    "type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-  glossary/",
    "title":"Member Exists",
    "status":400,
    "detail":"xxx@xxx.xx is in a compliance state due to unsubscribe, bounce, or compliance review and cannot be subscribed.",
    "instance":""
}
```

Comment: I got the same response except the title was: "Member In Compliance State"