# mailchimp batch subscribe from database usin api 3.0 syntax error

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I need to bulk update subscribers in my mailchimp lists using mailchimp's api and subscriber lists in my database.

I am trying implement the solution to the question here: [Mailchimp API 3.0 Batch Subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973388/mailchimp-api-3-0-batch-subscribe) but I am getting the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /myfilepath/addsubscribersfromdatabase.php on line 18" Code in question is below. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm supposed to use besides "["?

```
    <?php
$apikey  = 'myapi'; // Your Mailchimp ApiKey
$list_id = 'mylistid'; // your List ID Where you want to add subscriber

$servername = 'myserver';
$username   = 'myun';
$password   = 'mypw';
$dbname     = 'mydatabase';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql       = 'SELECT * FROM emails Limit 2';
$result    = $conn->query($sql);
$finalData = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $individulData = array(
            'apikey'        => $apikey,
            'email_address' => $row['email'],
            'status'        => $row['status'],//subscribe,pending,unsubscribe
            'merge_fields'  => array(
                'FNAME' => $row['FNAME'],
                'LNAME' => $row['LNAME'],
                'BARCODE' => $row['BARCODE'],
                'SERVICE' => $row['SERVICE'],
                'PURCHASE' => $row['PURCHASE'],
            )
        );

        $json_individulData        = json_encode($individulData);
        $finalData['operations'][] =
            array(
                "method" => "PUT",
                "path"   => "/lists/$list_id/members/",
                "body"   => $json_individulData
            );
    }
}

$api_response = batchSubscribe($finalData, $apikey);
print_r($api_response);
$conn->close();

/**
 * Mailchimp API- List Batch Subscribe added function
 *
 * @param array  $data   Passed you data as an array format.
 * @param string $apikey your mailchimp api key.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function batchSubscribe(array $data, $apikey)
{
    $auth          = base64_encode('user:' . $apikey);
    $json_postData = json_encode($data);
    $ch            = curl_init();
    $dataCenter    = substr($apikey, strpos($apikey, '-') + 1);
    $curlopt_url   = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches/';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_postData);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using an older version of PHP than that answer was written for.

The older way of writing that line is

```
$finalData = array();
```